# C++.NET WSDL Stubs fails when connection is lost

Tags: apache, tomcat, wsdl, c++-cli

We are using C++ .NET to contact a webservice through Apache (2.0.63) which load balances to a Tomcat server. We used wsdl version 2.0.50727.42 (Visual Studio 2005) to generate the webservice code from a WSDL file (duh).

We are using Apache to load balance for us and we can dynamically add worker servers (which happen to be Tomcat servers). During this add process we update the config files on the Apache service and then run Apache.exe -k restart.

What we are seeing is that if there is a load through our .NET client the client locks up when Apache is being restarted and all communication over the network ceases as confirmed by a wireshark. The client doesn't throw any exceptions so I'm not sure what the problem is. If anyone has any insight or has seen this before and knows that problem that would be helpful.